# equations with 3 numbers not displaying on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, equations

I'm writing a math problem generator, but when I run it only equations with 2 numbers are displayed, anything more and it says "undefined" and refuses to show the answer. Here is the entire code(please note it is incomplete right now)

```js
var type = 0;
var ans = 0;

function generatenumeral() {
    var num = (Math.round(1000 * Math.random())) / 100;
    var abs = Math.random();
    if (abs < .4) {
        num = num * -1;
    }
    console.log(num);
    return (num);
}

function generatelength() {
    var num = (Math.ceil(3 * Math.random()));
    console.log(num);
    return (num);
}

function generateSymbol() {
    var sign = 0;
    var num = (Math.round(12 * Math.random()));
    console.log(num);
    if (num === 0 || num == 1 || num == 9) {
        sign = "+";
    };
    if (num === 2 || num == 3 || num == 10) {
        sign = "-";
    };
    if (num === 4 || num == 5 || num == 11) {
        sign = "/";
    };
    if (num === 6 || num == 7 || num == 12) {
        sign = "*";
    };
    if (num == 8) {
        sign = "+";
    };
    return (sign);
}

function WarmUpAr() {
    var leng = generatelength();
    if (leng == 1) {
        var cool = twoNumb();
        return (cool);
    }
    if (leng == 2) {
        var cool = threNumb();
        return (cool);
    }
function twoNumb() {
    var sign = 0;
    var equation = 0;
    var a = generatenumeral();
    var b = generatenumeral();
    var siggn = generateSymbol();
    equation = a + " " + siggn + " " + b;
    if (siggn == "+") {
        ans = a + b;
    }
    if (siggn == "-") {
        ans = a - b;
    }
    if (siggn == "/") {
        ans = a / b;
    }
    if (siggn == "*") {
        ans = a * b;
    }
    return (equation);
}

function threNumb() {
    var sign = 0;
    var a = generatenumeral();
    var b = generatenumeral();
    var c = generatenumeral();
    var siggn = generateSymbol();
    var siggnA = generateSymbol();
    var equation = a + " " + siggn + " " + b +" "+ siggnA +" "+ c;
    if (siggn.equals("+")) {
        if (siggna.equals("+")) {
            ans = a + b + c;
        }
        if (siggna.equals("-")) {
            ans = (a + b) - c;
        }
        if (siggna.equals("/")) {
            ans = a + (b / c);
        }
        if (siggna.equals("*")) {
            ans = a + (b * c);
        }
    }
    if (siggn.equals("-")) {
        if (siggna.equals("+")) {
            ans = a - b + c;
        }
        if (siggna.equals("-")) {
            ans = (a - b) - c;
        }
        if (siggna == "/") {
            ans = a - (b / c);
        }
        if (siggna.equals("*")) {
            ans = a - (b * c);
        }
    }
    if (siggn.equals("/")) {
        if (siggna.equals("+")) {
            ans = (a / b) + c;
        }
        if (siggna.equals("-")) {
            ans = (a / b) - c;
        }
        if (siggna.equals("/")) {
            ans = (a / b) / c;
        }
        if (siggna.equals("*")) {
            ans = (a / b) * c;
        }
    }
    if (siggn.equals("*")) {
        if (siggna.equals("+")) {
            ans = (a * b) + c;
        }
        if (siggna.equals("-")) {
            ans = (a * b) - c;
        }
        if (siggna.equals("/")) {
            ans = (a * b) / c;
        }
        if (siggna.equals("*")) {
            ans = (a * b) * c;
        }
    }
    // if (siggn == "^") {
    //     var ba = Math.round(b);
    //     var count = 0;
    //     for (count = 0; count < ba; count += 1) {
    //         var ab = ab * a;
    //     }
    //     ans = ab;
    return (equation);
}
document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "not yet";

function arithmetic() {
    type = 1;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = WarmUpAr();
}

function preAlg() {
    type = 2;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "hello";
}

function Alg() {
    type = 3;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "This is cool";
}

function theAns() {
    document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = ans;
}
```

```html
    <p> "your warm up is....." </p>
    <button onclick="arithmetic()">Arithmetic Warm Up </button>
    <button onclick="preAlg()">PreAlg Warm Up </button>
    <button onclick="Alg()">Algerbra Warm Up </button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p>the answer is ....</p>
    <button onclick="theAns()">answer</button>
    <p id="ans"></p>
```

Comment: You have problem in `WarmUpAr` function. you missed `}`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the `WarmUpAr` funtion,that's why you are getting undefined error

Answer (score 0):

close this function WarmUpAr();

```
function WarmUpAr() {
var leng = generatelength();
if (leng == 1) {
    var cool = twoNumb();
    return (cool);
}
if (leng == 2) {
    var cool = threNumb();
    return (cool);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason threNumb() is failing is because your calling siggna.equals() in all your if statements. twoNumb() works because your using == instead of equals().

Also, in terms of calculating the answer to the equation, your doing it the hard way. In twoNumb() and threNumb() everything between where you set the 'equation' variable and where you return the 'equation' can be replaced with:

```
ans = eval(equation);
```